# Get back docker-for-windows Kuberentes kubeconfig file after deleting it

Tags: kubernetes, docker-for-windows, docker

My Docker for Windows `~/.kube/config` file was replaced when setting up access to cloud based K8s cluster.

Is there a way to re-create it without having to restart Docker for Windows Kubernetes?

*Update*
My current `~/.kube/config` file is now set to a GKE cluster. I don't want to reset Docker for Kubernetes and clobber it. Instead I want to create a separate kubeconfig file for Docker for Windows i.e. place it in some other location rather than `~/.kube/config`.

Comment: what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: See update above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to back up your `~/.kube/config` for GKE and then disable/reenable Kubernetes on Docker for Windows. Pull up a Windows command prompt:

```
copy \<where-your-.kube-is\config \<where-your-.kube-is\config.bak
```

Then follow [this](https://blog.docker.com/2018/01/docker-windows-desktop-now-kubernetes/). In essence, uncheck the box, wait for a few minutes and check it again.

[image: docker for windows]

You can re-recreate without disabling/reenabling Kubernetes on Docker but you will have to know exactly where your API server and credentials (certificates, etc):

```
 kubectl config set-context ...
 kubectl config use-context ...
```

What's odd is that you are specifying `~/.kube/config` where the `~` (tilde) thingy is unix/linux thing, but maybe what you mean is `$HOME`

Comment: classic turn it off and turn it on again, thanks that helped.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add to this, in case you are using wsl as kubectl/docker client as I am.
You can find your local kubernetes config in C:\Users\username\.kube\config.

You can then use that to [create a new kubernetes context for docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/working-with-contexts/).

For instance:
`cp /mnt/c/Users/username/.kube/config ~/.kube/docker-k8s.config`

`docker context create local-k8s --default-stack-orchestrator=kubernetes --kubernetes config-file=/home/username/.kube/docker-k8s.config --docker host=tcp://localhost:2375`

**Note:** I have exposed the docker engine on port 2375. The default settings for the unix sock type of connection can be found on the link above. You need to add the absolute path to the kubeconfig, you can't use '~'.

Then you can use `docker context use <context name>` to switch between your local docker-desktop kubernetes cluster and an external cloud env cluster with your docker client.

`docker context ls` will show the local existing contexts.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to access multiple clusters. One option is to play around with `KUBECONFIG` environmental variable. [Here is the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/).

> The KUBECONFIG environment variable is a list of paths to configuration files. The list is colon-delimited for Linux and Mac, and semicolon-delimited for Windows. If you have a KUBECONFIG environment variable, familiarize yourself with the configuration files in the list.

Or, you can provide an inline option.

```
kubectl config --kubeconfig=config-demo set-context dev-frontend --cluster=development --namespace=frontend --user=developer
kubectl config --kubeconfig=config-demo set-context dev-storage --cluster=development --namespace=storage --user=developer
kubectl config --kubeconfig=config-demo set-context exp-scratch --cluster=scratch --namespace=default --user=experimenter
```

And then use `use-context`

Answer (score 0):

I thought my config file was deleted, but my issue was that I was attached to an Azure AKS cluster using the Azure CLI and it changed my default context, so to switch over to the docker desktop cluster, I did the following:

#### Step 1: Determine the current context

```
kubectl config current-context
```

If it spits out anything other than `docker-desktop`, use this command to list all contexts available:

```
kubectl config get-contexts
```

#### Step 2: Switch contexts

Based on the contexts listed above, you should have see `docker-desktop` spit out as an option.  If not, follow the instructions from Rico and uninstall and reinstall Kubernetes for Docker Desktop; otherwise, switch contexts:

```
kubectl config use-context docker-desktop
```

#### Notes

- You can use this procedure to switch back to the previous context as well, so in my case, I could switch back to my Azure AKS cluster.
- On Windows, all these cluster names are in your `C:\Users\[YourIdHere]\.kube` directory inside the `config` file (along with the certificates and other data needed to connect to your cluster).