# How to add minikube in my kubeconfig file?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, kubeconfig

My kubeconfig file only includes docker-desktop, how to add cluster and user definitions of minikube to kubeconfig file to interact with kubectl command so with Monokle itself?

Comment: `minikube start` should do the setup for you.  Is it missing?  How can you tell?

Comment: I did minikube start and it is showing everything is fine...even the kubeconfig is configured but in the file, as opened in VS code is only showing me docker-desktop.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please feel free to provide more details on it what command you have tried and actually what you are trying to setup. ideally as David said `minikube start` will solve your issue by default it will set the entry of minikube, you can check all entry using `kubectl config get-contexts`

Answer (score 0):

Add cluster generally means referring to an existing cluster, which is done through [Docker context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/working-with-contexts/)

Then, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65200962/6309), switch to that context (and cluster) with `docker context use <context name>`.